# Navigation using react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm new in react native and I'm looking for an example of react navigation. I'm looking to create a home page similar to the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Would have been better to google that rather than asking a question on here, here's several snacks from `react-navigation` to look through: https://expo.io/snacks/@react-navigation

Comment: I googled and couldn't find it. Also, the link you sent to me, does not have an example of what I asked

Comment: It has an example on how to create the tabs. As far as the list goes, you would create a `stack navigator` for that tab with all the routes you want shown on it, and in the first screen of that stack you'd have a `FlatList` with several `Button`s, whose `onPress` prop would `navigate` using the `navigation` prop. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)

1. [Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#docsNav) - It let's you switch between screens. It creates a stack. It let's to navigate from one screen to another. When you press back button it navigates you back to the first screen. It
2. [Tab navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#docsNav)- It will create tabs as your picture.

In your case I think you will need a tab navigator which will be inside stack navigator.